# $\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}\in\mathbb N^*$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

A diligent student gives me (not for the first time!) a problem to solve; it is now:

Prove or disprove $$(m,n)\in \mathbb N^*\Rightarrow \frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}\in\mathbb N^*$$

Comment: Is the numerator supposed to be $(mn)!$?

Comment: Indeed. Or else the case $m = n = 2$ is an easy counterexample.

Comment: @Brian: I didn't know but ZeroXLR give us the answer.I edit.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\eqalign{\frac{((m+1)n)!}{(m+1)!(n!)^{m+1}}
  &=\frac{(mn+n)\cdots(mn+1)}{(m+1)n!}\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}\cr
  &=\frac{(mn+n-1)\cdots(mn+1)}{(n-1)!}\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}\cr
  &=\binom{mn+n-1}{n-1}\frac{(mn)!}{m!(n!)^m}\ ,\cr}$$
note that the first factor is an integer and use induction on $m$.

Answer (score 2):

How many ways are there to split $mn$ distinct students into $m$ groups of $n$ students each ?(The groups are not distinct).